# Are questions about HR approaches to hiring *specifically* programmers on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I was considering asking a question about [programmer skill not correlating to experience](http://blog.codinghorror.com/skill-disparities-in-programming/) versus HR/job offers pretty much defined by their "years of experience" qualifiers. It may still be too broad or opinion based, but is this question even on-topic since it really applies to HR and hiring rather than programmers?

Comment: To paraphrase someone: "Dear God No!"

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/40980

Comment: @gnat - but how to hire better programmers isn't career advice.

Comment: I think at one point those kinds of questions were accepted, back when this was a site to ask programmers questions that were not related to programming. But its not on-topic now. There are some [similar questions on Workplace.SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=years+experience) that may help you, or you can try asking a new question if you don't find an existing post that answers your question. I know they do have a [software-industry] tag that is meant to be for questions specific to the software industry, and don't think they'd mind such a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not a good fit.

Likely going to hit one of these in the tri-fecta:

- Off-topic: Career advice
- Too Broad
- Primarily opinion based.

---

And that having been said, the practice is not unique to programming.  Many fields filter by years of experience.  It might be on-topic on The Workplace, but it would be wise to check in their Meta first.

Comment: Or drop into [chat] and ask on The Whiteboard.

Comment: Sure, many fields filter by years of experience, but programming is the only one I know of where years of experience doesn't actually correlate to measurable performance.

Comment: Years of experience is a loose correlation, and an imperfect one at best.  I've seen tradesmen with "years of experience" that were decidedly lacking in ability.